# Vue Material Drawer (how to display file.vue inside of md-content)

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-material

I'm trying to build a website that contains 4 files.vue (navigation.vue, Home.vue, something1.vue something2.vue) each file has its own template and style. Inside of navigation.vue I have a temporary drawer in order to navigate on each files vue.

(documentation for temporary drawer: https://vuematerial.io/components/drawer (I'm using Vue material) I have use the same code).

inside of my drawer I do have the md-toolbar, md-drawer and md-content tags (in which it creates my navigation menu:

So, I was wondering if their is a way to load one of my template (by clicking on list of item in md-drawer) into the md-content tag?

Comment: try to  use vue-router

Comment: can u give me a example or the docs please

Comment: here the official docs https://router.vuejs.org/

Comment: an example that could help you https://codesandbox.io/s/oxlryzvzl9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use vue-router. To install vue-router, go to your root directory and type this in the terminal:

`npm install vue-router`

Sample code snippet for App.vue or where you want to render your .vue files:

```
<template>
<v-app>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</v-app>
</template>
```

Sample code snippet for routes.js file or where you'll be registering your routes:

```
// 0. If using a module system (e.g. via vue-cli), import Vue and VueRouter
// and then call `Vue.use(VueRouter)`.

// 1. Define route components.
// These can be imported from other files
import Home from './path/to/Home';
import Something1 from './path/to/Something1';
import Something2 from './path/to/Something2';

const routes = [
  {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/something1',
        name: 'Something1',
        component: Something1
    },
    {
        path: '/something2',
        name: 'Something2',
        component: Something2
    },
]

// 3. Create the router instance and pass the `routes` option
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

// 4. Create and mount the root instance.
// Make sure to inject the router with the router option to make the
// whole app router-aware.
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')

// Now the app has started!
```

You have to put each of your md options inside the vue-router-link like this:

```
    <md-drawer :md-active.sync="showNavigation">
      <md-toolbar class="md-transparent" md-elevation="0">
        <span class="md-title">My App name</span>
      </md-toolbar>

      <md-list>
        <md-list-item>
          <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
          <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
          <!-- replace "/foo" and "/bar" with your route path (e.g., "/home", "/something1", "/something2") -->
          <router-link to="/foo">
            <md-icon>move_to_inbox</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Inbox</span>
          </router-link>
        </md-list-item>

        <md-list-item>
          <router-link to="/bar">
            <md-icon>send</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Sent Mail</span>
          </router-link>
        </md-list-item>

        <md-list-item>
          <router-link to="/foo">
            <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Trash</span>
          </router-link>
        </md-list-item>

        <md-list-item>
          <router-link to="/bar">
            <md-icon>error</md-icon>
            <span class="md-list-item-text">Spam</span>
          </router-link>
          </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </md-drawer>
```

You can know more about vue-router here: [Vue Router Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html):

Feel free to upvote my answer if it helped you. Hope this helps! :)